# TypeLite -> TypeScript Enum -> Runtime error: Uncaught ReferenceError: TSEnum is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, typelite

We are using TypeLite to generate Enums in TypeScript.

C#:

```
[TsEnum(Module = "CustomEnum")]
public enum TSEnum {
    None,
    Test
}
```

http://type.litesolutions.net/

Generates this code in a file called Enums.ts:

```
namespace CustomEnum {
    export enum TSEnum {
        None = 0,
        Test =1
    }
}
```

As default TypeLite generates a `const enum` but in order to be able to get the names of the TypeScript enum entry `const` has been removed. This was done by editing `TypeLite.Net4.tt` and changing:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .ForLoadedAssemblies();
#>
```

To this:

```
<# var ts = TypeScript.Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .ForLoadedAssemblies()
        .AsConstEnums(false);
#>
```

https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issues/96/allow-option-of-export-const-enum-to-be

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums

I do not get any compile warning but at runtime I get the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TSEnum is not defined

Code generating error:

```
console.log(CustomEnum.TSEnum[CustomEnum.TSEnum.None]);
```

Or simply:

```
console.log(CustomEnum.TSEnum.None);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743651/3850405

If I however write it like this everything works:

```
enum TSEnum {
    None = 0,
    Test = 1,
}

console.log(TSEnum[TSEnum.None]);
```

What can I do to fix this? I'm using `webpack` for bundling if this could affect something. I have tried to import the Enums but it does not make any difference.

```
import '../../../Scripts/Enums';
```

If I manually entered `export` to `CustomEnum` and then imported the enum the code worked but the declarations that used `CustomEnum.TSEnum` in `TypeLite.Net4.d.tt` could no longer find the property.

```
import { TouchPoint } from '../../../Scripts/Enums';
```

Enums.ts:

```
export namespace CustomEnum {
    export enum TSEnum {
        None = 0,
        Test =1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a good solution so I decided to create a new enum object that can be used in front end. I removed `.AsConstEnums(false)` from `TypeLite.Net4.d.tt` and created the following code:

```
export enum TSEnumObject {
    None = CustomEnum.TSEnum.None,
    Test = CustomEnum.TSEnum.Test
}

console.log(TSEnumObject[TSEnumObject.None]);
```

Comment: FWIW I figured out that webpack seemed to ignore imports for any files that had a `/// <reference ...` tag for them, so I was able to get constants working as imported modules only after moving the constants to a separate file.